# How does "npm" run "npm test"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I always thought that `npm test` command just launches what I would write in `package.json` inside `scripts: { test: ...}` section. But I have this weird bug when it doesn't work.

So, I have this piece of config in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "test": "mocha tests/spec.js"
}
```

When I try to run tests I type `npm test` in terminal and had this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
```

But everything is OK when I type just `mocha tests/spec.js`. Any ideas why is that?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to install commander and I had an error **Cannot find module 'glob'**. After installing `glob` I have

> Error: Cannot find module '../'**

But actually question is why do I have these errors and why is everything OK when running `mocha tests/spec.js`?

Comment: Where is commander installed in your filesystem?

Comment: It does call the command specified in the scripts.test property of package.json, but it also sets up certain environment variables, such as PATH so you can refer to commands that only exist within your node_modules directory, but not installed globally.

Comment: Make sure to add commander to your package.json and `npm install` : )

Comment: @rninty I don't even know what `commander` is and why do I need it

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov It's probably a dependency of of another package you depend on.

Comment: @AlexWayne read please my last question

Answer (score 29):

You may have two versions of mocha installed: one globally (`npm install -g mocha`) and one locally, which appears to be broken.

When you run a script through `npm`, either as `npm run-script <name>` or with a defined shortcut like `npm test` or `npm start`, your current package directory's `bin` directory is placed at the front of your path.  For your package that's probably `./node_modules/.bin/`, which contains a link to your package's `mocha` executable script.

You can probably fix this by removing the local mocha and reinstalling it with --save-dev:

```
rm -rf node_modules/mocha
npm install --save-dev mocha
```

That should get you a working local copy of mocha with all its dependencies (commander etc.) installed.

Comment: Thanks! I found this answer because `npm help test` says: `This runs a package's "test" script, if one was provided.` but does not say where the ""test" script" is on the filesystem! Good to know it is in my "current package directory's `bin` directory" as you say here!

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the difference between "npm test" and "npm run test"

Comment: there is none. `npm test` is an alias for `npm run test`